# xlsx file corrupted during downloading from server

Tags: java, servlets

Folks, here is the situation:

1. confirmed that the xlsx file is good on the disc.
   I copied the file from server and can open without problems.
2. using FileInputStream and BufferedInputStream to handle the client side download function.
   The download function i mean user can download the file by clicking a hyperlink, and a servelet call was made to the java class which uses FileInputStream and BufferedInputStream
3. Mime type was set correctly as application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.shee

After download the file successfully, it will give a "converted failed" error while trying to use office 2003 to open this xlsx file.

any thoughts?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are bytes which didn't belong in the HTTP response body or were simply missing there.

It's impossible to point out the actual root cause based on the information given as far. You have to check if the right bytes were written from local disk file system to the HTTP response body.

Comment: Thank you. I just checked the sizes of input and output. They matched.

Comment: You are the man! I just use notepad to open those two files. You know what? the corrupted XLSX file added two empty lines in the content. No idea where this came from...

Comment: So, you was *actually* using JSP instead of Servlet to serve the file?

Comment: actually, i am calling that download Java function on a JSP page.

Comment: Ah OK. Whitespace outside *scriptlets* in JSP files is known to easily cause this kind of trouble. Well, then *somewhere* in the request-response chain you're doing a `response.getWriter().println()` or something. Or maybe you was *actually* using some `Reader/Writer` instead of `InputStream/OutputStream` to transfer the file.